# Is there a way of color-highlighting paired brackets in shell (bash)?

Tags: bash, command-line, colors, line-editor

Does anyone know if there is a way reproducing the same behaviour many text editors provide for colour-highlighting the syntax operators such as brackets or curly brackets. It would be very useful for complex one-liners in the terminal.

Example of the functionality I am talking about (from VIM).

[image: Example]

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you mean...

Comment: I mean if it's complicated, it should be in a script editor, i.e VIM

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean now and you are right. Nevertheless it is still very useful. Sometimes I am debugging some R code interactively, I need to paste some of the complex lines in the R-console and change some parameters. As R uses `.inputrc` I thought that I could make bash do these high-lightning and R could inherit.

Comment: You can run a terminal in Emacs. Its functions to find matching parentheses are available there. I do not know whether the same is possible in VIM.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a specific technical term for what I called color-highlighting? Maybe with a different keyword I may be able to fins something somewhere...

Comment: I believe the term is parenthesis (or bracket) matching. For bash, you could look at `blink-matching-paren`: [Bash readline blinking matching parentheses](http://superuser.com/questions/213872/bash-readline-blink-matching-paren-not-blinking-matching-parentheses)

Comment: @PetrUzel: I find your solution as the potential answer. Would you mind adding it as such so we close this question?

Comment: @Zorawar Somehow I missed your comment sorry. Adding `set blink-matching-paren on` to my `.inputrc` made this work perfectly whithin R

Comment: [Fish](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/) does it out of the box. Zsh can do it with some add-ons.

Comment: @pedrosaurio: that's OK. If you look around, you might be able to tweak the blinking behaviour (I don't know anything about it myself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When writing complex one liners in bash, it is handy to use readline's `edit-and-execute-command` (bound to `C-xC-e` by default in emacs mode). Hitting `C-xC-e` opens current commandline in the editor of your choice with all its fancy features. After saving it, bash will execute the contents as shell commands.

Alternatively, issue bash's builtin `fc` to open last command in the editor.

Comment: Perfect. Do you have an idea if I could get the same behaviour within the R-console? I know that R uses readline.

EDIT: @Zorawar 's link in the comment above solves this issue by adding `set blink-matching-paren on` in my `.inputrc` file